# jQuery plugin works offline but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline

There are 3 jQuery plugins that I'm using for a website I'm making and for some reason, one works perfectly fine but 2 do not. Here is the header area of my website with my links and such and the jQuery for the 2 plugins that don't work. The thing is, everything works perfectly offline but it doesn't work online. Any idea why? Thanks you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Mary E. Gonzalez Transitional Center for LGBT Youth</title>
   <meta name="description" content="Non-profit group for homeless LGBT teens in El Paso, TX">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <script src="slippry-1.3.1/dist/slippry.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="slippry-1.3.1/dist/slippry.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery('#image-slider').slippry();
      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#accordian h2").click(function(){
              $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
              if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){
                  $(this).next().slideDown();
              }
          });
       });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading different versions of jQuery:

- One from Google APIs.
- Second from jQuery Code.

Please remove one and it should work. Extract from your question:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- Removing the above line will make it work for sure. -->
```

Remove one of the two. Most likely, when you are offline, it loads a cached version of one jQuery and the other doesn't load, so it works.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much! I'm presenting what I have so far to the client today so this was pretty much life saving hahaha I didn't think I'd get an answer so quickly ^_^ Thank you!

Comment: @user2161312 Welcome. That's the power of StackOverflow.